# Save Chat Room in Contact List in Pidgin

Tags: ubuntu, instant-messaging, chat, pidgin

I use several chat rooms regularly with Pidgin.  Every time I want to join them, I need to pop-up the "Join Chat" dialog, select the right account, and enter the chat room name.  Sometimes, the some of the server information is not there so, I need to enter that in as well.

I was hoping there's a way to simply save a chat room in the contact list, so I can simply click it to rejoin the chat.  Is there?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From Buddy List: *Buddies → Add Chat*

From a chat window: *Conversation → Add...*

You'll find an auto-join option there, too.